# Emulate joystick with Python

Tags: python, virtual, arduino, joystick

I'm trying to use my [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) as a joystick, but I don't know how to set it as a joystick. I have an idea which is reading data from Arduino with Python and simulating the joystick. How can I implement a virtual joystick using Python? Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

Which flavor Arduino?

First, you need an Uno model, see:  http://arduino.cc/blog/2010/09/24/dinner-is-ready/

> We replaced the aging FTDI chipset
>   with a custom made usb-serial
>   converter built with an Atmel
>   ATmega8U2 this provides lower latency
>   and doesn’t require to install any
>   drivers on mac and linux (on windows
>   all you need is a simple .inf file)
>   more advanced users will be able to
>   reprogram the USB chip to make the
>   board show up as a variety of USB
>   devices (Keyboards, Mice, Joysticks,
>   MIDI etc)

Older models could only show up as serial ports (through the FTDI chipset).

Next, there's an article which shows how to emulate a joystick on the Uno (you will need to register on the Arduino forums to see the examples). See:  http://arduino.cc/blog/2010/10/24/arduino-uno-as-joystick/

Note:  you will have to replace the Arduino firmware.

Comment: Thank you for the answer payne! I' ve already found that article but I don't want to mess up my lovely arduino because I'm working on another project. It would be fantastic if there was a way emulating the joystick with python..

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I figure I'll try anyway - the forum post that details that method seems to have fallen off the internet - anyone happen to have a copy of it?

Answer (score 1):

It is a very old answer but i found a library that emulate a keyboard,is not same as joystick but if you use only digital button is good,I use only serial comunication through arduino and python.
I send a word through the serial to pc and python convert it in a keyboard key.
I wish there is a library that could emulate a joystick with axis.

Here is the library:
https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput